# Is it possible to get a list of all deleted items in a django model without the use of safedelete or softdelete?

Tags: django

I'd like to have a record for all deleted items presented to the user.
I've used safedelete but I want to change.

My model

```
class Issue(SafeDeleteModel):
    _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE
    borrower_id = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_id = models.ForeignKey(Books,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    return_date = models.DateField()
    issuer = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    DAYS = [(str(a), str(a)) for a in range(1, 21)]
    due_days = models.IntegerField(default=7,validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(3650),])
            
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.return_date = self.issue_date + datetime.timedelta(days=self.due_days)
        super(Issue, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        #unique_together = ('book_id','borrower_id'),
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['book_id', ]),
                   models.Index(fields=['borrower_id', ]),
                   ]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book_id)
```

Comment: What is your issue with those packages?

Comment: @lain Shelvington. safe/softdelete means the record is in in the system and therefore eats up my storage. Also it hinders me from using a unique_together

Comment: To display deleted records they must be stored somewhere, otherwise you wouldn't be able to present them. As for the constraint, you should be able to add a condition to make it work, can you share your model and which fields you want to add the index to?

Comment: @lain Shelvington, Added mymodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [UniqueConstraint with a condition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/#condition) to only enforce it under certain conditions

```
class Issue(SafeDeleteModel):
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        ...
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['book_id', 'borrower_id'], condition=Q(deleted__isnull=True), name='unique_book_id_borrower_id')
        ]
```

The package you are using seems fine for your use-case, the package [`django-simple-history`](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)  seems to also track deleted objects and doesn't store the data in the same table, might be worth a look if you want to store deleted data somewhere else

Comment: NameError: name 'UniqueConstraint' is not defined

Comment: @fakeMake it should be available in django.db.models - `models.UniqueConstraint`

Comment: unique_together = ('book_id','borrower_id'),. Is this line still neccessary or is it taken care of in the code you proposed???